# How to access python package metadata from within the python console?

Tags: python, distutils, python-packaging

If I have built a python package employing `distutils.core`, e.g. via

```
setup(
    ext_package="foo",
    author="me",
    version="1.0",
    description="foo package",
    packages=["foo",],
)
```

where does all the metadata go (what is it intended for?) and how can I access it from within python. Specifically, how can I access the author information from the python console after doing something like

```
>>> import foo
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to access the metadata is to use [pip](/questions/tagged/pip):

```
import pip

package = [pckg for pckg in pip.get_installed_distributions() 
            if pckg.project_name == 'package_name'][0]
#  package var will contain some metadata: version, project_name and others.
```

or `pkg_resources`

```
from pkg_resources import get_distribution

pkg = get_distribution('package_name')  # also contains a metadata
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have `pip` installed right now, so can't test it. The `pkg_resources.get_distribution` approach doesn't seem to work either for an extension that was installed via a simple `python setup.py build`. In this case I get a `DistributionNotFound: foo` exception.

Comment: python setup.py build does not install.

Comment: Use of `pip` adds an immense delay at the time of import, and adds a substantial memory footprint to your own code. It internally is just using `pkg_resources` and nets you an identical result; basically, `pip` here is extraneous and a misleading "solution". The answer also does not actually get the desired information; from a `Distribution` object it's extremely non-obvious how to get version, author, and description, amongst the other fields, back out. `pkg._get_metadata(pkg.PKG_INFO)` gets you the individual lines from the metadata file as a list, for starters.

Answer (score 23):

With python3.8 being released, you might want to use the new [`importlib.metadata`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/importlib.metadata.html)<sup>[1]</sup> module to parse any installed package's metadata.

Getting the author information would look like this:

```py
>>> from importlib import metadata
>>> metadata.metadata('foo')['Author']  # let's say you called your package 'foo'
'Arne'
```

And getting the version of your install:

```py
>>> from importlib import metadata
>>> metadata.version('foo')
'0.1.0'
```

Which is a lot more straight forward than what you had to do before.

---

<sup>[1] <sub>Also available as backport for Python2.7 and 3.5+ as [importlib-metadata](https://pypi.org/project/importlib-metadata/), thanks to @ChrisHunt for pointing that out.</sub></sup>

Comment: This is also available as a backport for Python 2.7 and 3.5+ in [importlib-metadata](https://pypi.org/project/importlib-metadata/).

Comment: if you're wondering why does a package not have metadata there, even though it gets imported just fine: it's the `.egg-info` directory missing

Answer (score 4):

The metadata are stored inside the `<package>-<version>-<py version>.egg-info` file.

when you create your module, you should have this line :

`Writing /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/foobar-1.0-py2.7.egg-info`

This file contain the Metadata :

```
Metadata-Version: 1.0
Name: Foobar
Version: 1.0
Summary: foobar
Home-page: http://foobar.com/
Author: foobar
Author-email: foobar@foobar.net
License: UNKNOWN
Description: UNKNOWN
Platform: UNKNOWN
```

If you want to access it, the best way is with `pip` or `pkg_resources` (as said Alexander Zhukov)
ex :

```
>>> import pkg_resources
>>> d = pkg_resources.get_distribution('Foobar')
>>> d.version
'1.0'
>>> d.location
'/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages'
```

Comment: Missing needed step to actually read back the metadata: `d._get_metadata(d.PKG_INFO)`  The bare Distribution object has no particularly obvious way of accessing the information.

Comment: @amcgregor your comment was actually the info I missed ! This would deserve being an answer of it's own

Answer (score 3):

## Solution

Although I prefer using `importlib.metadata`, since there is another answer already showing how to do that, I will show you another alternative.

For the purpose of illustration, I will use one of my own packages [`genespeak`](https://pypi.org/project/genespeak/) from PyPI.

### With `metadata`

```py
try:
    from importlib import metadata
except ImportError:  # for Python<3.8
    import importlib_metadata as metadata

print(metadata.name('genespeak')) # genespeak
print(metadata.version('genespeak')) # 0.0.7
```

### Use `pkginfo` [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/pkginfo/)

We will use the following 5 ways of accessing package information.

```py
from pkginfo import SDist, BDist, Wheel, Installed, Develop
```

#### A. Check Package Info from Source Distributions

Typically you would create the source distribution file with:

```sh
python setup.py sdist
```

Assuming you have a `.tar.gz` file at path: `./dist/genespeak-0.0.7.tar.gz`, here is what you need to extract the package info.

```py
from pkginfo import SDist

pkg = SDist("./dist/genespeak-0.0.7.tar.gz")
# Now you can access the metadata fields from 
# PKG-INFO file inside the source file:
# `./dist/genespeak-0.0.7.tar.gz`
print(pkg.name) # genespeak
print(pkg.version) # 0.0.7
```

#### B. Check Package Info from Binary Distributions

Typically you would create the binary distribution files (`.egg`) with:

```sh
python setup.py bdist_egg
```

Assuming you have a `.egg` file at path: `./dist/genespeak-0.0.7-py38.egg`, here is what you need to extract the package info.

```py
from pkginfo import BDist

pkg = BDist("./dist/genespeak-0.0.7-py38.egg")
# Now you can access the metadata fields from 
# the binary distribution file (*.egg):
# `./dist/genespeak-0.0.7-py38.egg`
print(pkg.name) # genespeak
print(pkg.version) # 0.0.7
```

#### C. Check Package Info from Wheel

Typically you would create the binary distribution wheel files (`.whl`) with:

```sh
python setup.py bdist_wheel
```

Assuming you have a `.whl` file at path: `./dist/genespeak-0.0.7-py3-none-any-whl`, here is what you need to extract the package info.

```py
from pkginfo import Wheel

pkg = Wheel("./dist/genespeak-0.0.7-py3-none-any-whl")
# Now you can access the metadata fields from 
# PKG-INFO file inside the source file:
# `./dist/genespeak-0.0.7-py3-none-any.whl`
print(pkg.name) # genespeak
print(pkg.version) # 0.0.7
```

#### D. Check Package Info from Installed Packages

See [here](https://pythonhosted.org/pkginfo/distributions.html#introspecting-installed-packages) for more details

```py
from pkginfo import Installed
import genespeak

pkg = Installed(genespeak)
# Now you can access the metadata fields from 
# PKG-INFO file inside the source file:
# `./dist/genespeak-0.0.7.tar.gz`
print(pkg.name) # genespeak
print(pkg.version) # 0.0.7
```

#### E. Check Package Info from Development Directory

```py
from pkginfo import Develop

dev = Develop(".")
# Now you can access the metadata fields from 
# PKG-INFO file under `genespeak.egg-info` 
# directory under the project root.
print(dev.name) # genespeak
print(dev.version) # 0.0.7
```

### References

- `pkginfo` [Docs](https://pythonhosted.org/pkginfo/distributions.html#introspecting-source-distributions)

Comment: @dastrobu Perhaps your question has been long answered. However, another option could always come handy.

Answer (score 2):

Concerning the `version` metadata only, I found it quite unreliable to use the various tools available as most of them do not cover all cases. For example

- built-in modules
- modules not installed but just added to the python path (by your IDE for example)
- two versions of the same module available (one in python path superseding the one installed)

Since we needed a reliable way to get the version of *any* package, module or submodule, I ended up writing [getversion](https://smarie.github.io/python-getversion/). It is quite simple to use:

```
from getversion import get_module_version
import foo
version, details = get_module_version(foo)
```

See the [documentation](https://smarie.github.io/python-getversion/) for details.

Answer (score 1):

Given `setup.py` as follows:

```
from distutils.core import setup

setup(
    name         = 'TestApp',
    version      = '0.0.1',
    author       = 'saaj',
    py_modules   = ['app'],
    test_suite   = 'test'
)
```

For some scripting and automation without installing the package, where `pip`, `easy_install` and even `setuptools` don't provide command line options or public APIs for reading all metadata (e.g. `test_suite`), here's a little hacky way:

```
python3 -c "import sys, types; m = types.ModuleType('distutils.core'); \
    m.setup = lambda **kwargs: print(kwargs); \
    sys.modules['distutils.core'] = m; import setup"
```

This will print a `dict` of keyword arguments passed to `setup()`.

```
{'author': 'saaj', 'version': '0.0.1', 'name': 'TestApp', 
    'test_suite': 'test', 'py_modules': ['app']}
```

You can replace `print` in the `lambda` to whatever output you need. If your `setup.py` imports `setup()` from `setuptools`, which is actually the recommended way, just replace "distutils.core" with "setuptools" in the snippet.

Formatted snippet follows:

```
import sys
import types

m = types.ModuleType('distutils.core')
m.setup = lambda **kwargs: print(kwargs)
sys.modules['distutils.core'] = m

import setup  # import you setup.py with mocked setup()
```

Answer (score -2):

One use of this data is that it is displayed on Pypi (http://pypi.python.org/) if you were to publish your package there.  One way to structure it is like so:

in the top level of your `foo` module:

```
__author__= "me"
__version__= "1.0"
__description__= "foo package"
```

in `setup.py`:

```
import foo
setup(

    author = foo.__author__,
    version = foo.__version__,
    description = foo.__description__,
    packages = ["foo",],

)
```

This way you only need to update your metadata in one place, and as the data is defined in your packages main module, it will be accessible from there.

Comment: There's a vitally important catch-22 here.  Your setup script now depends on the package it's installing being already installed (or, at least, already importable).  That's not a good thing.  (Down vote for potentially dangerous practice.)